# UITableView: Can't find a way to move/align the tableIndex element up

Tags: ios, uitableview, table-index

I have a UITableView and I am using a tableIndex, my problem is that when the keyboard comes up, it partially hides the tableIndex.

[image: i]

An acceptable solution would be to move the tableIndex up (like what the Contacts App does) when the keyboard appears, and show the most of it, but can figure out a way to do this. Any ideas of code snippet I can try?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to register to Keyboard Will Show notification and then update the height of your controller's view. You could also embed everything in a scroll View so that once the keyboard rises, your view becomes smaller and scrollable.

It is honestly a bit annoying to set up, so, if you are open to using CocoaPods then IQKeyboardManager is probably your best bet which can be found here: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager